# В админке не работает тэг <audio controls> в safari

Tags: html, django, django-rest-framework

Я пытаюсь добавить в админку плеер для воспроизведения аудио

```
class Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('player',)

    readonly_fields = ('player',)

    def player(self, obj):
        template = f'<audio controls>' \
                   f'<source src={obj.get_url()} type=audio/mpeg>' \
                   f'<source src={obj.get_url()} type="audio/ogg">'\
                   f'</audio>'
        return mark_safe(template)
```

Подаю аудио в формате mp3:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В chrome все работает, в safari выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Читал, что :

*В Safari на iOS  , предварительную загрузку и автозапуск отключен. Никакие данные не загружаются, пока пользователь не инициирует их.*

Но, как я понял это касается autoplay

Также читал, что controls поддерживается в safari: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Можно ли решить как-то данную проблему?

Comment: Ну так аудио в каком формате-то? Может, Safari просто не поддерживает этот формат

Comment: @andreymal Аудио в формате mp3

Answer (score 0):

type=audio/mpeg   - Нет

type="audio/mpeg" - Да

И если файл формата mp3, то надо указать type="audio/mp3"

Надеюсь помог)

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло :(
Где я читал, пишут type="audio/mpeg"